# How to replace component when v-bind is already used and it's inside loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The problem I'm encountering is like this.

```
<div v-for="(obj, index) in objects">
    <button @click="changeComponent(index, 'A')>Change to A</button>
    <button @click="changeComponent(index, 'B')>Change to B</button>
    <ComponentA v-bind:obj="obj" />
</div>
...
components: {
    ComponentA,
    ComponentB,
}
data() {
    return {
        objects: [
            { name: 'A' }
        ]
    }
},
methods: {
    changeName(index, name) {
        this.objects[index].name = name
        }
    }
```

What I want to do is to replace component depending on the `obj`'s `name`.
However there are some problems. First I thought I could use `v-bind:is` but I already used `v-bind` to pass value to child component. Second even if I can use `v-bind:is` I still don't know how to access to its `index` in `computed` method. Is there other good way to do it? How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `:is` to set your component. You can also bind props with this. Something like this should work

```
<div v-for="(obj, index) in objects">
  <button @click="changeComponent(index, 'A')>Change to A</button>
  <button @click="changeComponent(index, 'B')>Change to B</button>
  <component :is="objToComponent[obj.name]" v-bind:obj="obj" />
</div>
...
components: {
 ComponentA,
 ComponentB,
}
data() {
  return {
    objects: [
        { name: 'A' }
    ],
    objToComponent: {
      'A': 'ComponentA',
      'B': 'ComponentB'
    }
 }
},
methods: {
 changeName(index, name) {
    this.objects[index].name = name
    }
 }
```

The main changes are:

- added an object that maps names to component names, so Vue know what you want to render
- used `:is` so you are able to change the component based on `obj.name`

Comment: Thaks a lot. It works but what is the difference between `v-bind:is` and `:is`?

Comment: None, it is just shorter. Your v-bind:obj can be shortened to :obj. Just like @event is a shorthand for v-on:event

Answer (score 0):

Well, to do so, you can use `:is` for making the dynamic component.

> Used for dynamic components and to work around limitations of in-DOM templates.

Here is the working [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/varit05/hmgtezfp/)

Here is the official [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#is)

Hope this helps